# How Do I approach this geometrical locus problem?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let the equal sides $AB$ and $AC$ of an isosceles triangle be produced to $E$ and $F$ so that $$BE\times CF = AB^2.$$
Show that the line $EF$ will always pass through a fixed point.

Comment: Are you saying that $$BE\times CF=AB^2?$$

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for an approach I'm not giving a full solution.

Let P and Q be the points on AB and AC produced such that AB=BP and AC=CQ. Join EF  and let it intersect PQ at R. Using whatever way you wish, find the ratio PR:RQ.

Spoiler: The ratio will come out a constant.

Comment: It's a pain to type math on phones so if someone wants to (constructively) edit this they're more than welcome.